# Rotate canvas outside of onDraw

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas

How can you rotate the canvas outside of the onDraw method? Is that possible?

I know that I can rotate it the following way inside, but I need alter the canvas from another method in a different class.

```
public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
   int width = super.getWidth();
   int height = super.getHeight();
   canvas.scale(1f, -1f, width * 0.5f, height * 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: @pskink I want to hit a button and rotate the whole canvas.

Comment: what about RotateAnimation?

Comment: @pskink im not familiar with RotateAnimation, but I can look into it.